# Is there any way to keep masses of tag revisions out of the "active" question list?

Tags: discussion, editing

The title pretty much says it all.

I think the work of fixing improperly-tagged questions is important, and often a particular user will take it upon him/herself to add/remove tags from a series of questions.  This is good.  But it does lead to stuff like today:

[image]

The "active" questions list is dominated by old, answered questions which are only present because they're being re-tagged.  So thank you to @RosieF for doing this work, but is there any way to keep tag-only edits out of the active list?

Comment: Unfortunately, I think the answer to your question is, "No."

Comment: [I've started a bounty on a meta question exactly on this topic.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29394/it-should-be-possible-to-retag-a-question-without-bumping-it-to-the-front-page)

Comment: @Emrakul Good idea, thanks! (It's all right for some, with their masses of rep on main meta ... :-P )

Comment: @rand can't stop won't stop

Comment: @Emrakul Thanks!  That would seem to be a plausible and potentially implementable feature.  I think the comment on that Meta post is relevant here: smaller SE sites that have slower question turnover are more affected by these bumps.

Answer (score 6):

### No.

Sorry, but it's pretty much as simple as that. See [It should be possible to retag a question without bumping it to the front page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29394/it-should-be-possible-to-retag-a-question-without-bumping-it-to-the-front-page), a feature request on main meta which has never been implemented.

---

The only special cases are:

- **tag merging** (*mod-only*) - a stronger form of synonymisation. If tag X is merged with tag Y, then all questions tagged X are automatically retagged Y instead.
- **burnination** (*CM-only*) - getting rid of a tag completely. If tag X is burninated, it disappears from all questions, and questions tagged *only* with X become [untagged](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged).

Neither of these can be done by 'mortal' users, so if you want tags merged or burninated, you need to propose it on meta and get a consensus. More importantly, **most retagging operations can't be achieved using these means**. E.g. if there's a bunch of questions tagged [logical-deduction](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logical-deduction) which should really be [riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/riddle), then you have to do it by hand, since both these tags should exist separately.