# What is the current editing policy of this site?

Tags: discussion

I came across this heavily edited puzzle https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/43575/cipher-cipher-ciphers.

[image]

In the comment section a fairly new user is warned by one of our moderator team members, not to edit their post frequently. The presense of the moderator indicates, that something *might be* off here.

I think users making efforts to improve their submissions should be encouraged, or, the very least, their actions should be tolerated. I don't see this warning justified here. Also, since there is currently a [massive retagging effort](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5485/is-there-any-way-to-keep-masses-of-tag-revisions-out-of-the-active-question-li) going on I don't quite see how a couple of edits by the OP is more distractive than those. I am not a big fan of puzzles full of grammatical mistakes, as it is always unclear whether they are deliberate, or just English is not the native language of the OP.

But my opinion is besides the point. My question is:

> **when is it acceptable to edit my own question? Is it better to leave a typo here and there, in order to avoid any unnecessary extra attention?**

I was actually thinking of rising some old questions from the dead (also called as *necromancing*) by means of editing them. Would that be OK?

Comment: I am the author of that question. I edited it to correct some potential grammatical mistakes, nothing more, nothing less. Don't make any other assumptions based on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Editing questions is fine.

Editing questions *repeatedly* for the sole purpose of drawing attention is not.

If it's a very minor issue, I usually err on the side of leaving it - I generally don't like to be seen as "rep-farming" or "attention-farming". But there's not a problem with editing in general.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question.

Comment: ^vote with a note: Minor edits can be noted in comments until enough of them accumulate to warrant a post edit, or until a more significant reason to edit comes along.